# Error parsing HTML in Android with JSOUP

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse the following link:

http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1

As you can see it is a very simple page and I am just trying to extract the text on the page with `JSoup`. My current implementation returns the wrong HTML and I am not sure why. Here is my code:

```
public class RetreiveCurrencies extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Document html = null;
        try {
            Log.i("wbbug",arg0[0]);
            html = Jsoup.parse((arg0[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("wbbug",html.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Which is called with:

`AsyncTask<String, Void, String> rc = new RetreiveCurrencies().execute("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1");`

However, instead of returning the correct HTML with the text you see when clicking the link, my Log.i returns:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1
   </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I extract the text you see when clicking the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jsoup.parse()` takes a String argument, so currently your code is parsing the URL as if it was a String of html code.

To parse a Document from a remote URL you should use `Jsoup.connect()`, for example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
```

For your specific example (which appears to be returning JSON, not HTML):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR&q=1").ignoreContentType(true).get();
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

Will output:

```
{"to": "EUR", "rate": 0.73757499999999998, "from": "USD", "v": 0.73757499999999998}
```

The reason I had to add `ignoreContentType(true)` is because otherwise it throws an `UnsupportedMimeTypeException`.